# Add items from the select list from Db Repository ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to populate the select list in my view with the data I have in a repository. I tried using ViewData as will be shown in the code below but I am getting this error.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

The select list looks like this.

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label asp-for="Category" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select asp-for="Category" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" placeholder="Category" asp-items="@ViewData["categories"]"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Category" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller looks like this

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    this.ViewData["categories"] = _categoryRepository.Categories; 
    return View();
}
```

Any solution to this error, or otherwise what is the best way to get the repository data to the view?

Comment: try this:
ViewData["categories"]=_categoryRepository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.Title});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items attribute value of `select` is a collection of `SelectListItem`. So you have to convert this as following:

```
this.ViewData["categories"] = _categoryRepository.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem {
            Value = x.ToString(),
            Text = x.ToString()
        }).ToList();
```

In Razor, we can update this as to

```
 <select asp-for="Category" class="custom-select mr-sm-2" placeholder="Category" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["categories"])">
     <option value="">Select one</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Just to see if understood thing correctly, this works cause the data from the repository has to be in SelectListitem object to be used in a SelectList. Thank you again for the solution.